# How do I connect different parts on Blender?

Tags: blender

I'm new to blender, trying to make my first model. I've got a body, a shoulder, an arm and a head - all separated. How do I connect them correctly?

[shapes http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/fr.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/fr.png)

Comment: Not your fault you didn't see that duplicate. I just edited the title so it would be more generic to the situation.

Answer (score 4):

if parts are in the same object:

You can make new faces by selecting at least 2 edges and typing [F]. If you 2 have edgeloops with the same edge count you can use bridge [W]->Bridge. You can also merge vertecies. To do so, you need to select verts desired to be merged and type [alt]+ [M] and choose option. you can also access this menu from [W]->Merge

If parts are multiple objects:

select multiple objects and type [ctrl]+[j] and it will join selected to active object

tip: when you are making model and know that it will need connecting przepare the same edge count on both borders.

edit:

I would advice you to learn about topology if you are serious about modeling, ex.: http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-series/learning-mesh-topology-collection/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Vertex Snapping :)
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Modeling/Meshes/Snap_to_Mesh

You can merge two vertexes/faces/edges so that they become one

Here I found some Youtube vid tutorial that might help you get started: Search for "Vertex Snapping Blender"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hCwO1KfbcQ